# Handling Error in asynchronous process using @Async annotation on custom method vs on @Gateways method

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I have a process where I need to upload file to Sftp server asynchronously. So after exploring more about Async in gateways I found that I need to have error channel defined in `@MessagingGateway` parameter then handler to handle the Exception propagated to error channel but I felt handling this way is complicated for me, as I will have to update Pojo field and persist into DB depending on the file upload, success or failure.

So I thought of having a custom method annotated with `@Async` and call the gateway method. Also surround gateway method with try block and catch any exception occurred in the downstream

Code Sample:

```
 @Async
void upload(Resource file, FileStatus fileStatus){
    try{
        uploadGateway.upload(file,fileStatus.getFilePath(),fileStatus.getFileName());
    }catch(RuntimeException e){
        fileStatus.setUploadStatus("Failed");
        //save into db
    }
}
```

Upload Gateway without error channel so that error can be sent back to caller

```
 @MessagingGateway
 public interface UploadGateway {


@Gateway(requestChannel = "input.channel")
void upload(@Payload Resource file, @Header("path") String path, @Header("name") String fileName);
}
```

Handler:

```
 @Bean
public IntegrationFlow uploadDocument() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("input.channel")
            .log(LoggingHandler.Level.WARN)
            .handle(Sftp.outboundAdapter(sftpSessionFactory(), FileExistsMode.FAIL)
                    .autoCreateDirectory(true)
                    .remoteDirectoryExpression("headers['path']")
                    .fileNameExpression("headers['name']"))
            .get();
}
```

Question:
What will be the consequences if I'm handling error this way? Is this the right way to handle any error occurred in downstream flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `@MessagingGateway` is like an RPC in messaging, it is fully OK to catch an exception on its method call like that. Since you make your flow fully sync, it works like typical Java exceptions sub-system.

Your concern about async error handling with `errorChannel` really makes sense since it is similar in complexity with standard Java async method handling and its errors processing.

On the other hand it is really commended to handle errors downstream via `errorChannel` if that is going to be some complex logic in some other flow. Plus you are going to return back some compensation message.

However in the end of day the choice is yours: there is no drawbacks to handle errors yourself.

See [Error Handling](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/error-handling.html#error-handling) chapter for more food to think on.

Comment: What if my flow or handler is also asynchronous and doesn't execute on caller's thread will it still work? Or do I have to introduce errorChannel mechanism then?

Comment: No, you don't. When we send a message from gateway, we add `errorChannel` header. Typically the `TaskExecutor` in the framework is wrapped into an `ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor` which knows what to do with that header. Even if it is an async downstream, it is still sync in the gateway: it waits for a reply in the `TemporaryReplyChannel`, which may re-throw an exception placed into it via `errorChannel` header.